# Web3 - Provider not set or invalid

Tags: reactjs, next.js, blockchain, web3js

I'm trying to connect my frontend (Nextjs) with my contract on the Rinkeby Network ([token on etherscan](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/token/0xe71c56d861f90bf96c9f006d25ce91da97ddb238)). I'm new to the crypto space, so I'm not sure what provider it's talking about... I thought the connection was made with the useWeb3 hook, and everything was handled by Infura. I also want to note that I can connect to the Ethereum network with this setup, but not to my token on the Ethereum network.

I have this setup on my frontend:

`./src/pages/index.tsx`:

```js
import type { NextPage } from "next";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useWeb3 } from "@openzeppelin/network/react";
import { createContract } from "../lib/herbie";

const Index: NextPage<IndexProps> = () => {
  const { networkId, networkName, providerName, accounts, lib } = useWeb3(
    `wss://rinkeby.infura.io/ws/v3/${process.env.INFURA_PROJECT_ID}`
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchContract = async (): Promise<any> => {
      if (networkId === 4 && accounts.length > 0) {
        const contract = await createContract();

        console.log({ contract });

        console.log(contract.methods.balanceOf(accounts[0]).call()); // ERROR HERE
      }
    };

    fetchContract();
  }, [accounts, networkId]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>
        {JSON.stringify({
          networkId,
          networkName,
          providerName,
          accounts,
        })}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Index;
```

`./src/lib/herbie.ts`:

```js
import Web3 from "web3";

const getAbi = async (): Promise<string> => {
  const abi = await (await fetch("/abi.json")).json();

  return abi;
};

const createContract = async (): Promise<any> => {
  const herbieContract = new Web3().eth.Contract;

  return new herbieContract(
    (await getAbi()) as any,
    "0xe71c56d861f90bf96c9f006d25ce91da97ddb238"
  );
};

export { getAbi, createContract };
```

I get the following error:

[image]

My metamask:

[image]

Comment: Why are you over-abstracting so much? You've created a bunch of unnecessary functions. Just inline it. Look at the amount of code you've had to post just to showcase your problem...

Comment: I know, because like i said, I'm new to the web3/crypto space and I'm not sure where this error is coming from. Also, I'm abstracting because I'm a frontend developer and I like to keep my logic away from my UI.

Comment: You should extract logic into hooks. Your abstraction makes it harder to reason about the code. It's uneccessary.

Comment: oh yeah, i'm just messing around trying to get into this stuff.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the provider into the contract instance as it says in the [documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-contract.html)

```
const contract = new Web3().eth.Contract(abi, address);
Contract.setProvider(`wss://rinkeby.infura.io/ws/v3/${process.env.INFURA_PROJECT_ID}`);
```

Almost all production code uses ethersjs instead of web3js btw.

It looks like this instead:

```
const contract = new Contract(address, abi, library);
```

Comment: Ok I'll give it a shot. what is the library though? is that the same as what is returned by the `useWeb3` hook?

Comment: Yes exactly - the library is returned from the web3 hook. Also, consider using useDapp library. It contains further abstractions from the useWeb3 library and is a bit more user friendly.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting abi and address to create the contract but to be able to interact with the blockchain, you need a provider. `provider` is kinda a bridge that connects your contract to the blockchain.

to load the provider you could use [@metamask/detect-provider](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@metamask/detect-provider), you can get the provider in one line:

```
import detectEthereumProvider from '@metamask/detect-provider'

const provider = await detectEthereumProvider()
```

I manually load the provider to show what happens behind the scene:

```
const [web3Api, setWeb3Api] = useState({
    provider: null,
    web3: null,
    contract:contract
  })


useEffect(() => {
    const loadProvider = async () => {
      // I assume your code to load contract is working
      const contract=  await createContract()
      let provider = null;
      // early metamask injects ethereum
      if (window.ethereum) {
        provider = window.ethereum;
        try {
          await provider.enable();
        } catch {
          console.error("User denied accounts access!")
        }
      }
      // new version metamask injects web3
      else if (window.web3) {
        provider = window.web3.currentProvider
      }
      else if (!process.env.production) {
        // this is ganache provider in development
        provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:7545")
      }
    if (provider) {
        setWeb3Api({
           web3: new Web3(provider),
           provider,
           contract
    })
  } else {
    console.error("Please, install Metamask.")
  }
   }
    loadProvider()
  }, [])
```